# How can I connect a Raritan Peppercon Eric Express remote management card to my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, remote-access, pci-express, remote-control

I want to be able to turn my computer on/off remotely at the hardware level and am looking to buy this card: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Raritan-Peppercon-Eric-Express-Remote-Management-Hardware-based-remote-control-/372654971381

My understanding is that I would connect the cable coming from the on/off buttons on my case to the card and then connect the card to the motherboard, allowing me to turn the computer on/off using either the normal buttons or via an ethernet cable connected to the card.

However, I am struggling to find which type of cable I need to connect the card to the motherboard.

All my system components are on PC Part Picker [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/MdN8Bb). Since the Asrock Z170M Extreme4 motherboard does not have a PCI slot (which is required by the card) I am planning to buy [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-PCI-Express-Adapter-Card/dp/B0024CV3SA/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=pci%2Bto%2Bpcie&qid=1572130633&s=electronics&sr=1-3&th=1) PCIe to PCI adapter.

Comment: Ad says Card only, No cable or Software which you will need both. I would buy a newer card that has everything you need.

Comment: Yeah hence the question - are there any more modern cards that are OS/hardware independent as this one is? From my understanding these days this kind of functionality is built into motherboards (IPMI) and cards like this are no longer being produced

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Where should they be asked instead? I noticed 'hardware recommendations' but it's in beta - this one looked the next most appropriate

Comment: There is no problem it being in beta is there?